# How do I create several triggers for the same EJB @Timeout method?

Tags: java, timer, ejb-3.1

[JSR-000318](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr318/index.html) spec defines the TimerService (chapter 18).

Given an EJB, you can create an **automatic timer** or a **programmatic timer**.

An **automatic timer** looks like this

```
@Schedules(
{
  @Schedule(hour=”12”, dayOfWeek=”Mon-Thu”),
  @Schedule(hour=”11”, dayOfWeek=”Fri”)
})
public void sendLunchNotification() { ... }
```

While a **programmatic timer** looks like this

```
@Resource
private TimerService timerService;

void someMethod(){
   ScheduleExpression exp = new ScheduleExpression();
   (... set exp ...)
   TimerConfig config = new TimerConfig();
   (... set config ...)
   Timer created = timerService.createCalendarTimer(exp,config);
}
```

When a **programmatic timer** is created, the task to be triggered by the timer is that one annotated with @Timeout

My question, since I could not find it clearly stated in the JSR, if a create 2 **programmatic timers** for the same EJB using the same ScheduleExpression, the container must call the @Timeout method **twice** or **once**?

To make my question clearer.

Let's suppose I've created 2 programmatic timers. Each one has a different metadata (stored in the serializable timer INFO attribute). Then, I'd like to have two different timers, and when the @Timeout method executes, it would get this INFO attribute to choose what to do.

If the answer of my question is **twice**, than I can do it. If the answer of my question is **once**, then I cannot.

Notice that if the answer is **once**, it makes some sense from the performance point of view, because you don't actually need to notify the EJB more than once for a given moment, even if you have several triggers for it, but if you are planning to deal with these triggers independently (because each one has a different INFO), then someone is just ignoring the attempt to create a timer when there's already one persisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timers are distinct, so if you create two, then the @Timeout method will be invoked for both timers regardless of whether the scheduling information is the same.

Comment: that's what I've thought too, but that's not how apache TomEE+ is implemented

Comment: they claim "Spec doesnt say/mandate anything when it comes to persistence"

Comment: There is a difference between a timer *instance* (createXTimer) and a timer *expiration* (timeout method called at time X). Each timer instance is guaranteed to fire independently, but for a persistent timer, a single expiration might should only occur on one JVM successfully. (An unsuccessful expiration will retry at least once. Non-persistent timer expirations also only occur on one JVM successfully, but for `@Schedule`, a unique timer instance is created for each JVM.)

Comment: not sure if I got it. My question is about programmatic timers. A timer can be programmatic (not defined by a Schedule annotation) and persistent at the same time. My question is: if I've created 2 programmatic timers, of course they will execute the same Timeout method, but will this method be executed twice or once, if both programmatic timers have the same schedule? Your first answer matches my opinion, but I don't get your latest comment.

Comment: If you create 2 programmatic timers, then they will fire independently even if they have the same schedule. They just happen to call the same timeout method when they fire.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class TestBean {

    // should be in a separate class
    public enum TTimer {
        FOO,
        BAR
    }

    @Resource
    TimerService timerService;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initSingleTimer() {
        removeRunningTimers();
        startInitialTimer();
    }

    private void removeRunningTimers() {
        for (Timer t : timerService.getTimers()) {
            if ( t.getInfo().equals(TTimer.FOO)) {
                t.cancel();
                log.trace("LogWatcher: Running timer canceled");                    
            }
        }
    }

    private void startInitialTimer() {
        ....
        timerService.createTimer(startDate, interval, TTimer.FOO);
    }
```